# Wrap characters which aren't contained in a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a website with Game maker tutorials. Sometimes I have to put a few lines of code onto the website. To make it look more like Game maker itself, I would like to change the color of specific characters and words in the text.

Right now I'm trying to change the color of all the X and Y's. This is what I have right now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".code").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\x\b/g, "<font color=red>x</font>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\X\b/g, "<font color=red>X</font>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\y\b/g, "<font color=red>y</font>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\Y\b/g, "<font color=red>Y</font>"));
    });
})
```

While it does color the characters, it also colours characters in a word, which is not what I want. What do I add or change so it will only color X and Y's that are not in a word?

Comment: Note that the method you're using will potentially break the HTML in the page if an `X` or `Y` is in an attribute of an element. Instead it would be better to loop over the `textNodes` within the whole document and update them if they contain the text you're looking for. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16662482/519413) for how to do that.

Comment: Also wrap in a span with a class instead of using deprecated font

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but before I'll read the code in detail I want to know if it will actually replace texts, because as far as I've read at the moment it seems like it will only wrap words in a span

Comment: I hope you ll check the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

I think these codes can solve your problem. Just started with `\b` for regex

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".code").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\b\x\b/g, "<font color=red>x</font>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\b\X\b/g, "<font color=red>X</font>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\b\y\b/g, "<font color=red>y</font>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\b\Y\b/g, "<font color=red>Y</font>"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fno9d6wz/

Comment: @Lolslayer you are well come please vote and check the answer :)