# How to add HTML tags around variating expression with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna add HTML tags around a markup [x,y] with x and y change may vary. I try to use some Regex to get these texts but i don't have the desired result.

I use this proposition : [Insert HTML into text node with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662393/insert-html-into-text-node-with-javascript)

In my page, there is

> [x,y] markup who x and y are number between -99 and 99

This markup is write manually in a text editor and be part of content for an article related to a video game and there may be multiple markups in the same page.

So I need to replace all

```
 [x,y] to <em class="position">[x,y]</em>
```

I try these regex :

```
\[(.*?)\] (but add only <em> on . in the page)
\[0-9+\] (but add one <em> for each number in [x,y])
```

The objective is allow user to click on these elements to copy it to clipboard. (this second part works fine)

Anyone can help me ? :)

Comment: 1) is the markup always varying/changing? 2) is the only constantly reliable pattern indeed just something like that ... `<element ... ></element>`? 3) if the markup does vary, can you please provide some more markup example code ... maybe some markup that really differs from each other?

Comment: Before one is going to upvotes this Q. one should maybe think about if this question was ask in a way that one really understands the OP's base problem. What was provided so far leaves more space for guessing than for coming up with a reliable approach.

Comment: Hi, the markup is [x,y] with x and y can be number positive or negative, like [-10,77] or [24,87] , technically, x and y can values are between -99 and 99

Comment: Does any of the answers is what you're looking for? If not, please clarify. What should be the result for some common cases.

Comment: @SalakissODV ... This is not an answer. It just repeats the information already provided with the Q. Please edit your Q. in a way that one gets an understanding about the input data or the data that needs to be processed. Like is there already markup and where does it come from. If e.g. your `text` looks like this ... `[10,24] or [14,-25] or [x,y]` .., will the replacement be 3-times `<em class="position">[x,y]</em>`?

Comment: @SalakissODV ... thanks for editing. And it looks like *blex* and *Yousaf* meanwhile provided already sufficient enough solutions, even though one of the reg-expressions does not fulfill yet the criteria of ... [*"The markup is \[x,y\] with x and y are number between -99 and 99."*](https://regex101.com/r/FrT7y6/4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.match()` function to extract the `[x,y]` combinations from the string and then replace these matched combinations with the `<em>` tag

#### Non-duplicate coordinates

If there are no duplicate coordinates in the text, then use following approach

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
let str = p.textContent;
const regex = /(\[-?\d{1,2},-?\d{1,2}\])+/g;
const matches = str.match(regex);

matches.forEach(m => (str = str.replace(m, `<em class="position">${m}</em>`)));
p.innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.position {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>[10,24] or [14,-25] or [-100,-210] or [-99,99]</p>
```

#### Duplicate coordinates

If there are duplicate coordinates, then use following approach

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
let str = p.textContent;
const regex = /(\[-?\d{1,2},-?\d{1,2}\])+/g;
const matches = str.match(regex);

matches.forEach((m, i) => {
  str = str.split(m).join(`<em class="position">${m}</em>`);
});

p.innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.position {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>[10,24] or [10,24] or [14,-25] or [14,-25] or [-100,-210] or [-99,99]</p>
```

Comment: Note: this won't work with `[10,24] or [10,24]`. Good job on the `-99` to `99` requirement, though

Comment: The `match` based approach is error prone to any coordinate-duplicate. While iterating the `matches` list any duplicate will be replaced again and again in `str` at its first occurrence; thus one does create nested markup for the first occurring coordinate and misses the ones that have not yet been and will never bee replaced in `str`.

Comment: @SalakissODV ... so far just a combination of *Yousaf*'s regex and *blex*'s approach would meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: Answer edited. Added an alternative approach to handle the string with duplicate coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace()`, and pass it a regex. More explanation on the regex I used:

[image]
*([Courtesy of Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xeDoBI/1))*

Demo:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');

p.innerHTML = p.innerText.replace(/(\[-?\d+,-?\d+\])/g, '<em class="position">$1</em>');
```

```css
.position { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
```

```html
<p>[10,24] or [14,-25] or [x,y] (← these are not valid numbers)</p>
```

Comment: or `replace(/(\[[^\]]+\])/g, '<em class="position">$1</em>');`

Comment: @MoshFeu Oh, nice one! Thanks

Comment: @blex ... your regex matches beyond an ideal use case also every bracket-pair in e.g. [`[,], [ ], [x,], [x,y,z]`](https://regex101.com/r/FrT7y6/3). This might be reliable enough. The OP's Q was mentioning ... *"The markup is [x,y] with x and y are number between -99 and 99."* ... though.

Comment: @PeterSeliger you're right. That was mentionned by the OP after I answered. I'll edit the answer